# Como quitar el estilo de botones y dropdown menu en Internet explorer

Tags: css, wordpress, internet-explorer

Buenas quiero quitar el estilo predeterminado de botones de internet explorer, he probado con -webkit-appearance:inherit; y none pero ambos funcionando en chrome mozilla y safari en explorer no me acaban de funcionar adjunto fotos para ver diferencia.
[image]

Quiero quitar los estilos de los botones y dropdown menus de una pagina wordpress usé esto:

tengo puesto

```
-moz-appearance:inherit; -o-appearance:inherit;
 -ms-appearance:inherit;
 appearance:inherit;
 -webkit-appearance:inherit;
```

Y aún así en Internet Explorer no funciona. Me funciona en Opera, Firefox y Chrome. ¿Alguna idea?

[image]

Comment: ¿Puedes poner código en lugar de imágenes?. El prefijo  `-webkit` es para navegadores basados en ese motor, internet explorer no usa webkit.

Comment: `-webkit` es el prefijo para navegadores basados en webkit, que no es el caso. Inténtalo usando `-ms-appearance`

Comment: Parece que en IE no funciona, en Edge sí pero extrañamente usa el prefijo `-webkit` en lugar de `-ms`, segun [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=appearance): _Microsoft Edge and IE Mobile support this property with the -webkit- prefix, rather than -ms- for interop reasons._

Comment: tengo puesto -moz-appearance:inherit;
-o-appearance:inherit;
-ms-appearance:inherit;
appearance:inherit;
-webkit-appearance:inherit;
 y aún así en internet explorer no funciona

Comment: ¿Has visto el enlace de _caniuse_ que puse? Esa propiedad no tiene soporte en IE

Comment: edge imita webkit, internet explorer (prefijo ms-) es otro motor (trident)

Comment: Edge, el más reciente, usa webkit. Si usas IE para la prueba, no es lo mismo como te indican en los comentarios.

Answer (score 1):

A ver si esto te funciona:

```
input[type="submit"],
input[type="reset"],
input[type="button"],
button {
  background: none;
  border: 0;
  color: inherit;
  /* cursor: default; */
  font: inherit;
  line-height: normal;
  overflow: visible;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-user-select: none; /* for button */
   -webkit-appearance: button; /* for input */
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
}
```

Comment: Por qué tu código resuelve el problema? Procura siempre explicar, al menos brevemente, cómo usar el código que propones.